# Why can we take out the Real part operator from under the integral?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Suppose I'm integrating $ \int e^x \cdot \cos(x) dx$ and instead of the usual double partial integration, I say that since $ \cos(x) = \Re [{e^{ix} }]$ I'll just integrate $ \int \exp (x+ix)dx$ and take the real part of this to find the original integral. My question is how did we justify going from $$ \int e^x \cdot \Re[e^{ix}]dx$$ to $$ \Re \Big [\int e^{x+ix} dx\Big] $$

Comment: Is it fundamentally because it is a linear operator?

Comment: By definition $\int (f+ig)=\int f +i \int g$ if $f$ and $g$ are real valued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have tagged this real analysis,  Kavi Rama Murthy's comment is the best answer.  If this were an "intro to complex" class, I'd say

Discarding the complex part for each term in a Riemann sum is equivalent to waiting to the end and discarding all of them at once.

Here, this relies on

- $\mathrm{e}^x \in \Bbb{R}$
- The sum of two complex numbers has real part equal to the sum of the real parts and imaginary part equal to the sum of the imaginary parts.